# need to click twice on an added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery to add a some content to a page:

```
$('#upper').on("click",'a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('new')) {
        $('#lower').load(url);
    }
});
```

It works fine but the added content includes some links. I.e.:

```
<table class="report">
    <tr>
        <td class="report">
            <a href="sofferenze/anag_dett.php?id_ndg=PG010000001" class="cred_link col0 ">PG010000001</a>
        </td>
        <td class="report">società</td>
        <td class="report">LSSF Consulting SRL</td>
        <td class="report">
            <a href="sofferenze/anag_dett.php?id_ndg=PF010000002" class="cred_link col3 ">PF010000002</a>
        </td>
        <td class="report">IC - Intestatario di un credito</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

First time I click on the href nothing happens. Second time it works fine . Looks like I miss something in the code I have posted to focus the added content. Any advice? Will try to create a fiddle in the meanwhile (never done before...)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: You mean you have to click twice on added anchors to get the default behaviour of clicked anchor or to get any bound handler to be fired?! Please improve your question with concrete example and better a jsfiddle

Comment: @A.Wolff The OP means for loaded links.

Comment: @C-link Ya, if by 'loaded links' OP means new added anchors in `#lower`, that's what i understand

Comment: setTimeout would help.

Comment: @A.Wolff ummm, that might be even #upper the loaded links

Comment: @C-link setTimeout(), why that? Maybe OP is binding in some way handler without setting it in load() complete callback and without using delegation, who knows?!

Comment: I thought because when loaded immediately clicked to that link would be problem, so..

Comment: @C-link no, it is not a matter of waiting. Looks like the dom doesn't recognize the elements added in the lower div by the .load event. They are recognized in the DOM only when I first click.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Then what about triggering click event? $('#upper a').trigger('click');  ???

Comment: @LelioFaieta Any online link we can check your issue?

Comment: @A.Wolff setting up a jsfiddle to check it